# How to add default Options for markers

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I want to add a different icon to the markers that are created when i click with the marker drawing control.(react-google-maps package)

I tried addding a markerOptions prop in the DrawingManager component but it doesnt seem to work like polygonOptions work.

```
<GoogleMap defaultZoom={13} defaultCenter={{ lat: 38.022871, lng: 23.790431 }}>
        <DrawingManager
          ref={props.onDrawingManagerMounted}
          defaultDrawingMode={this.state.currentDrawingMode}
          defaultOptions={{
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
              drawingModes: [
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER
              ]
            },
            polygonOptions: this.colorOptions(),
            markerOptions: {
              icon: {
                url: require("../../../assets/images/helipadIcon.png"),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(5, 58)
              }
            }
          }}
```

Comment: After some testing I found out that the markerOptions does work and the problem was that when I was displaying the markers I didnt pull their icon to use. I solved that with a icon={this.markerArray[i].getIcon()} prop on each marker component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick tipp: name the package that you are using before you ask your question. It took me a while to find the react-google-maps package on npm.

Check out the official documentation of the named package: https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/

You will find out that the `DrawingManager` component doesn't offer a prop named `markerOptions` or `polygonOptions`. Instead use the `Marker` component (https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#marker) which offers a property `icon` of type `any`.

`<Marker icon={} .../>`

If you want to change/edit markers that have been drawn using the `DrawingManager`, you can use the `onMarkerComplete` callback function that will return the `marker` object. You can use the marker object to change the icon. See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/drawing#DrawingManager.markercomplete

```
const icon = {
   url: require("../../../assets/images/helipadIcon.png"),
   anchor: new google.maps.Point(5, 58)
};
const onMarkerComplete = (marker) => {
   marker.setIcon(icon);
}

return (
<DrawingManager onMarkerComplete={onMarkerComplete} ...>
...
</DrawingManager>
);
```

Comment: You are right I forgot to add it in the text only in the tags below. The thing is that the documentation doesnt mention polygonOptions either but they work. Theres also a circleOptions etc.

Comment: The icon works in the marker component I have tried that but I want to change the icons of the markers that are going to be created by pressing a button. So I press a button then set in the state the icon chosen and then set that as default icon marker in the drawing manager. I mean if I add a marker component in the drawing manager component that is only going to display that marker right? I want the newly created markers to be displayed with a different icon